# Configuring OpenVPN to share internet

Tags: fedora, openvpn

my university is providing OpenVPN to provide public internet IP address for students (for some libraries etc.) - in other words, they are sharing their internet connection via openVPN...

I would like to do same thing in my home server, but I have no idea, how to configure it...

I've finished first 13 points following the manual ( http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Openvpn ). But have no clue, what should be in server.conf and how to set fedora 17 firewall (propably iptables).

Server has one interface `em1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500` which has private network address (192.168.20.0/24). NAT router is configured to send all incoming traffic to the server (DMZ).

Can somebody send me simple example of OpenVpn server and client config file, to share internet -> when somebody connect to my OpenVPN, he can access internet services in his computer with my IP address?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
rpm -ql openvpn | grep ample-config-fil
```

There are already some examples on your installation.
You should first think about different Use cases.
Roadwarrior or Site to Site VPN.

Answer (score 1):

The really lazy answer is [OpenVPN Access Server](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/overview.html). It does all the hard work for you and is really easy to set up.